# How to read files in C# in a directory whose names contain a specific word?

Tags: c#, directory, filenames

I have a directory on my `C:` drive called `practice`. I have txt files there with these names: `CityUpdated`, `TownUpdated`, `MetroNotUpdated`, `SuburbNotUpdated`.

I want to write some C# code that reads the text files whose names contain the word "Updated". But I can't figure out how to do this using `Directory.GetFiles`. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: They are all `*Updated` files... the naming convention is biting you :-)

Comment: Supposing I had text files called CityUpdated, TownUpdated, IncorrectInfo. How would I read only the files which contain "Updated"? Just Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Test", "*Updated.txt")) doesnt seem to work

Comment: @Here it works correctly... Various possibilities: the files don't have a .txt extension (remember that windows normally hides extensions), or they aren't in C:\Test . Try going in `cmd.exe`, then go in `C:\Test` and do a `dir`

Comment: It still doesnt work. I did what you said. Can you suggest another way?

Comment: Do a `Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Test", "*")` and see what files it finds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\test","*updated*");` instead of `Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\test","*updated.txt");`. This will help you.

P.S: I'm posting this as an answer because I couldn't comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles("c:\practice", "*updated.txt").Where( f => !f.Contains("NotUpdated"));
```

this give you an array with the right filenames.